# How to authenticate the class in Laravel 5 before acessing it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am authenticating my users in following way

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use Session;
use Validator;

class CollectionloginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getIndex(){
        return View('collectionmodule/login');
    }

    public function postCollectionlogin(){

            $rules = array(

           'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'

            );

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                return redirect('collection/login')->withErrors($validator);

            }else {

                  $cred = array(
                        'email' => Input::get('email'),
                        'password' => Input::get('password')
                    );

                $role = User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->first();

                if (Auth::attempt($cred) && $role->role == 'collector'){
                    if (Auth::check()){
                        Session::put('role','collector');
                        Session::put('name',Auth::user()->name);
                        return redirect('collection/home');
                    }

                } 
                else{
                        Session::flush();
                        Auth::logout();
                        return redirect('collection/login')->with('login_errors',true);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

and My routes are

```
//Collection started by vikram
Route::controller('collection/login','CollectionloginController');
Route::controller('collection/home','CollectionController');

Route::get('collection', function () {
    return view('collectionmodule.login');
});

Route::get('collection/logout',function(){
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('collection/target');
});
```

And the controller is

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;

class CollectionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

  public function getIndex(){

    $empid= Auth::user()->empid;
    $invoice = Invoice::orderBy('Id', 'desc')->get();


    return View('collectionmodule/home')->with(array('invoices'=>$invoice));
}
}
```

My problem is How to Authenticate the class `collectionContorller` before accessing any of the functions , Like if the authenticated user is not collector it should redirect back to the login page

I have similar trouble with other classes also

One method I have figured is something like this

```
  public function __construct(){
          if(Session::get('role')!="collector"){
          $validotrs= "The User is not a collector";
        return redirect('collection/login')->withErrors($validator);
}
    }
```

Can any one help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't set the Session manually. If the user is logged in you have access to it via the `Auth` facade like this: `Auth::user()`.

But basically, if you want to check your current setup for authentication or anything other before requests get processed you should use a [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware).

```
php artisan make:middleware Collector
```

Within the newly created file under `App\Http\Middleware\Collector` you can change the `handle` function to represent your logic:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::get('role') != "collector")
        return redirect('collection/login');

    // Alternatively, using Auth Facade

    if ($request->user()->role != 'collector')
        return redirect('collection/login');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now you have to register the middleware in `App\Http\Kernel.php` in the `$routeMiddleware` array.

```
'collector' => \App\Http\Middleware\Collector::class,
```

In your Collectors-Controller you now can reference it like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('collector');
}
```

On every request to the controller the `collector` middleware gets checked and performs the logic defined by you.

**Edit:**

If you need dynamic middleware it looks like this:

```
# /App/Http/Middlware/Role.php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if ($request->user()->role != $role)
        return redirect('collection/login');

    return $next($request);
}
```

And in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('role:collector'); // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
}
```

Comment: I have like few more Modules like , Sales,Admin etc so for each will I have to create one Middle ware or I can create Some common MiddleWare class and add Functions to filter each Role ?? , Like We use to do In before Filter

Comment: so to create adynamic middleware do I have to run the same artisan command ?

Comment: one more problem is that I have different login pages for different modules so how will I redirect them , Like I have collection/login , sales/login etc . maybe I can use $role and validate using that

Comment: You can run the command again but you don't have to. You can also rename the class if you want to. The command just generates the file.
For your other problem: You can expand the handle function with a `$loginPath` variable (although I have no idea why you have separate login-pages) and call it like this: `$this->middleware('role:collector,sales/login');`

Comment: `if ($request->user()->role != $role){

                if($role=="collector")
                return redirect('collection/login');

                if($role=="target")
                return redirect('targetmodule/login');
`  I am doing it something like this I hope this is not a wrong way

Comment: But its throwing error `Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Middleware\Role::handle()`

Comment: Did you see my edit about dynamic middleware? You also have to specify the variable in your controller like this: `$this->middleware('role:yourrole');`. The colon is important!

Comment: yes I did that  I have implemented everything correctly

Comment: You sure? The error clearly says, that the 3rd argument ($role) is missing. Maybe the error gets thrown by another controller where you haven't implemented it yet?

Comment: for now I was testing only one controller which was base_url/collection/login  , so I implemented only there , Maybe I will have to do that in all my controllers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92838/discussion-between-tim-and-vikram).